# Finding the number of two consecutive vowels in a string does not work

Tags: c, string

When two vowels come one after another then the count should increment.But i dont know why its incrementing it more than that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(void)
{       
    int i,j,count=0;
    char string[80];
    printf("Enter a string:\n");
    gets(string);
    for(i=0; ;i++)
    {
        if(string[i]=='\0')
            break;
        if(string[i]=='a'||string[i]=='A'||string[i]=='e'||string[i]=='E'||string[i]=='i'||string[i]=='I'||string[i]=='o'||string[i]=='O'||string[i]=='u'||string[i]=='U')
        {
            if(string[i+1]=='a'||string[i]=='A'||string[i]=='e'||string[i]=='E'||string[i]=='i'||string[i]=='I'||string[i]=='o'||string[i]=='O'||string[i]=='u'||string[i]=='U')
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: A bunch of your `[i]` s should be `[i + 1]` s

Comment: Please note: (a) never use `void main` (b) always return an int (0 for success), (c) ideally don't use the non-standard and non-portable <conio.h> and functions therein - use standard C library functions instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For once, be as lazy as you can. If you have to repeat a portion of code, ask yourself if you can't do it without repeating.

I would have gone for that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const size_t MAX_LENGTH = 100;

//Counts the occurrences of two consecutive same characters
//in a string, without case
size_t cnt_doubled(char const * const str, int c) {
    size_t ret = 0;

    //A pointer browses the string until terminating char and
    //increments ret if the pointed char is the one seeked
    //two chars in a row
    for(char const *p = str ; *p != '\0' ; ++p) {
        ret += tolower(*p) == tolower(c) && tolower(*(p+1)) == tolower(c);
    }

    return ret;
}

//Explicit...
size_t cnt_doubled_vowels(char *str) {
    char const *vowels = "aeiouy";

    //A pointer browses the vowels and takes into account
    //the occurrences in the string of every char pointed
    size_t n_vowels = 0;
    for(char const *p = vowels ; *p != '\0' ; ++p) {
        n_vowels += cnt_doubled(str, *p);
    }

    return n_vowels;
}

int main(void) {
    //fgets returns a string terminated by a newline char (before
    //terminating char of course) but in your case it doesn't
    //matter
    char string[MAX_LENGTH] = "";
    fgets(string, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

    printf("N : %d", cnt_doubled_vowels(string));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hem, why did I get a down vote ? At least comment to say why.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have a typo here, your code:

```
if(string[i]=='a'||string[i]=='A'||string[i]=='e'||string[i]=='E'||string[i]=='i'||string[i]=='I'||string[i]=='o'||string[i]=='O'||string[i]=='u'||string[i]=='U')
{
    if(string[i+1]=='a'||string[i]=='A'||string[i]=='e'||string[i]=='E'||string[i]=='i'||string[i]=='I'||string[i]=='o'||string[i]=='O'||string[i]=='u'||string[i]=='U')
        count++;
}
```

Notice the second if statement there, everything except the first condition is checking string[i] instead of string[i+1].  So if you have 'A' in string[i], then this will increment count no matter what is in string[i+1].

You want:

```
if(string[i]=='a'||string[i]=='A'||string[i]=='e'||string[i]=='E'||string[i]=='i'||string[i]=='I'||string[i]=='o'||string[i]=='O'||string[i]=='u'||string[i]=='U')
{
    if(string[i+1]=='a'||string[i+1]=='A'||string[i+1]=='e'||string[i+1]=='E'||string[i+1]=='i'||string[i+1]=='I'||string[i+1]=='o'||string[i+1]=='O'||string[i+1]=='u'||string[i+1]=='U')
        count++;
}
```

I also recommend you look up the function `tolower` which will lower-case a character, meaning you need to do less comparisons which will make this code much easier to read and maintain.  Also you might consider using a switch or any array hereand probably writing a helper function.

I guess I just can't stand this code as it is, here's a better version:

```
int is_vowel(char ch)
{
    switch (tolower(ch))
    {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then make your if statement:

```
if (is_vowel(string[i]) && is_vowel(string[i+1]))
    count++;
```

See, much cleaner and easier to read, don't you think?

Comment: That horrible `if` statement and even the `switch` can be replaced with a simple `strchr`: `if ((NULL != strchr("aeiou", tolower(string[i]))) && (NULL != strchr("aeiou", tolower(string[i+1]))))`. Nevertheless, it's more readable to use an `is_vowel`-like function.

Comment: @the_void: The `tolower` isn't even necessary if you're going to use `strchr()` - just use `"AaEeIiOoUu"` as the search string.

Comment: @Above: I read that strchr finds the first occurence of the entered character in the string.But you all are using "AaEeIiOoUu" (More than one characters) How is it going to work?

Answer (score 2):

You also have a buffer overflow:

```
gets(string);
```

And the following is bad style:

```
for(i=0; ;i++)
    {
        if(string[i]=='\0')
            break;
```

should be

```
for(i=0; string[i]!='\0';i++)
```

Comment: I just find it easy to understand :)